# Fast choosing of bits from a set

Tags: optimization, language-agnostic, montecarlo

I'd like to choose a number of random bits from a known bitmask. Ideally I'd like to choose those bits in a random order too, but the task can be split into choosing and shuffling later.

Some additional characteristics of the data:

- the bitmask is 64 bit long
- number of selected bits is either 4, 8, 16, or 32
- usually between 40 and 60 bits will be set (always at least half)
- I need millions of random choices for a single bitmask (results are used for statistical simulation)

Here's an example of mask and things I'd expect (choosing random 4 bits):

```
mask    0111111011111011111110111111111111111101111111100111101111111111
random4 ....1...........1........1...............1......................
shuffled bit positions: 41, 16, 4, 25
```

In this example I shouldn't get back bit position 0, because it's already disabled.

This is a known hotspot of the algorithm, so I'd like to squeeze as much performance out of it as possible (test on the random choice takes only ~2 times longer than my current random choice implementation). My current idea is to fill the first `n` numbers in a `char positions[64]` with positions of bits set in the bitmask. So for the example above I'd end up with: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, ...]`. Then start choosing random numbers between `0` and `n` to choose a random bit position. After each choice set the position to -1 and repeat a random choice if I hit a -1 again.

This is great for choosing 4 numbers, but gets repeated choices too often when choosing 32 numbers.

Another idea would be to create an array of positions as above, then shuffle it using Fisher–Yates and choose the first `n` positions. This requires more writes in the array and always needs to generate as many random numbers as there are set bits which may be an overkill for choosing 4 bits only.

Are there any faster ways to generate this data? I'm aiming for the accuracy of the simulation, so it's really about how many random iterations can I check in a second.

Language is not important really, but I guess C will dominate here.

Comment: I'd try to use first if you need <1/2 of available numbers and second one otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do a full Fisher-Yates shuffle. Simply stop after you have the first `n` values. You can even reuse the partially shuffled array for the next sample. Here's an example in C99:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Assumes that the array a contains numbers 0..63 in any order
static void print_random_bits(uint64_t bitmask, int num_bits, int a[64]) {
    for (int i = 0, j = 63; i < num_bits; ++i, --j) {
        int r = rand() % (j + 1);
        int t = a[r];
        if (r != j) {
            a[r] = a[j];
            a[j] = t;
        }
        printf("random bit %2d: %d\n", t, bitmask & (1ULL << t) ? 1 : 0);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int a[64];

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
        a[i] = i;
    }

    uint64_t bitmask = 0x5555555555555555ULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        print_random_bits(bitmask, 8, a);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```